# Google sheet Array Function auto fill

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello i am trying to make google sheet array function to auto fill formula in case of Column C
have any value Like a,b,c, Etc i have try this but its not work

```
=arrayformula(IF(C2:C="","",F1-D2:D+E2:E))
```

[image]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Can you explain teh result you want to achieve.

Comment: Kindly check i update images

Answer (score 0):

### First solution

in F1

```
=arrayformula(E1:E-D1:D)
```

in G1

```
=arrayformula(SUMIF(ROW(D1:D),"<="&ROW(D1:D),F1:F))
```

[image]

### other solution, in F1

```
=arrayformula(mmult(1*(transpose(row(D1:D))<=row(D1:D)),E1:E-D1:D))
```

[MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292)

[image]

Comment: Kindly check image again i update correct now

Comment: It could be easier if you share a spreadsheet. What are your locale ?

Comment: I have posted 2 solutions. E1 will contain the first value instead of F1.

Answer (score 0):

Try This !

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C="",,INDIRECT("F1:F"&ROWS(F:F)-1)-D2:D+E2:E))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).